# If condition is meet but is ignored in PHP code

Tags: php, if-statement, isset

I have the following code to validate if a username is entered:

```
 if (!isset($_POST['username']) ) {
    
    header("location: index.php");
    $error_message = "Please enter your Username and Password!";
    exit();
 }
```

If I don't enter any value in the username field, the condition turns out false and would execute the code inside the `if` statement and similar situation when I enter a username!

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Did you inspect the network request if there is indeed a username sent? Maybe you have an error with your form?

Comment: Inspecting the network request shows username is sent. `username=&password=`

Comment: Well, then the answer is obvious: the field is set. If you want to check anything else than "is this field set", you need to use any other condition (like: `empty()` to check whether it contains any data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a form with an `<input name="username">` then this input will *always*  have some sort of value. If you don't enter anything, the value is still the empty string. And of course that empty string is posted to the server.

On the other hand PHP [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) checks

> "if a variable is declared and is different than null"

And of course this is `true` even for the empty string (ie `username` exists and it's different from `null`). If you want to catch all situations where your `username` is either not existing at all or an empty string you can for instance do as follows

```
if (!isset($_POST['username']) || trim($_POST['username']) === '' )
```

or you can use

```
if (strlen($_POST['username']) == 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This makes sense now.